# .htaccess conditional RewriteBase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, ssl

The following is a part of the .htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on    
    #RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteBase /~example/    
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
  </IfModule>
```

When I remove the comment before RewriteBase, I could able to access my website via the shared SSL offered by the webhost:
`https://secure.myhost/~example/`. However, it causes a server error when I tried access it with non secure via `http://example.com`

My question is about: Is there any way to make .htaccess to consider RewriteBase conditionally based on HTTPS or HTTP ?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rules need some refactoring I thing. Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /~example/

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on    
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    RewriteRule (?!webroot/)^(.*)$ webroot/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution cause the same internal server error on trying access the website via http too. However, it works with https.

Comment: It is not wordpress app. It is a cakephp application. I use this code in the .htaccess of the public_html root directory.

Comment: No I don't have any VirtualHost entries.

Comment: Ok in Cakephp is there any place where you define base URL has `https://`? Somewhere `https` is being enforced.

Comment: Really, I don't know! However, I will add cakephp tag to see any additional help. thank you very much.

Comment: Ok just for testing can you please comment `RewriteBase` line and `webroot` lines and then test.

Comment: Commenting RewriteBase, leads to inaccessibility via https, it returns 404 not found error. In cakephp webroot line should not be commented because it will corrupt routing of cakephp controller's actions.

Comment: What is your DOCUMENT_ROOT value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36198/discussion-between-ss-and-anubhava)